# Customized cultures cannot be passed LCID, only by name, Parameter name: culture

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm using crystal report in my VB.net application, when I show the Report and try to print it I face this error :

> Customized cultures cannot be passed LCID, only by name, Parameter name: culture

The printing works fine on my computer but the problem on client computer.

this the error picture :

[image]

Comment: Have you set anything to do with cultures in your program?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes I'm using the currency sample by using .tostring("C2")
and in the crystal design I'm using the currency sample by format option.

Comment: Unless someone comes along with a better suggestion, a search for "Customized cultures cannot be passed LCID, only by name, Parameter name: culture" might give you useful information. Which version of the .NET Framework is it using?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I already searched and I couldn't fined a solution, I'm using .NET 4.0 , but i changed it to 4.6 and i had the same problem

Comment: If you set your computer's regional settings the same as the client's computer's settings, can you reproduce the error? I notice that there is a print dialog displayed - at exactly what point does the error message appear (e.g. when the dialog appears, when choosing a printer, when clicking print, or something else)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton when clicking the print button on the print dialog.
the error message appears then when you press ok the app Freezes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after searching, I found the solution :

By change the region settings of the operation system to a format whose LCID does not equal 4096. The format can be changed in Control Panel > Region > Formats.